# What's that sentence will be?

Tags: lateral-thinking

> Once a king asked his adviser to write down
>   a sentence that, when he reads it in happiness
>   he becomes sad and when he reads it in sadness
>   he becomes happy.

What's that sentence will be ?

Comment: King Akbar and Birbal?

Comment: could be many things - like "It's gonna change", "it's not going to last" etc.

Comment: Yes, King Akbar Birbal. I have read some puzzles of them and also i found some questions here like that, so I asked my first but simple puzzle here.

Comment: @Stender - I think they all boil down to variations of the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He says

> **The time will pass soon.**

Because

> If he is happy he know he will not be happy for long.

And

> If he is sad he know he will not be sad for long.

Answer (score 4):

I know there's a perfect answer to that, but here's a bit of funny answer.

> I'll assume both the king and his advisor are also programmers (Yes, he's a modern king) So the sentence will actually read:
> *public static void main(string args[]) { KingsMood = !KingsMood; }*

Comment: But if King is JavaScript developer, then condition may differ than this, bit long with conditional statement ;)